# Is it possible to allow ArcGIS Online users to set visibility range?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.4

I'm not certain you are able to do this or not but is it possible to create a widget or something in an AGOL app to allow a user to set their own visibility range for a layer?

This is outside of me setting the visibility range for everyone as an administrator. I've had several requests from my users to allow them to change their own visibility ranges for certain layers.

Comment: Do these users have access through the organizational account?

Comment: Yes, they've been granted access to the apps.